# Pagination in Wear OS

Tags: android, pagination, navigation, wear-os

Good Morning, I'm developing a new Wear OS application. The thing is, I can't find anywhere how to make a good **pagination**.
I would like to change activity on swipe (no matter if it's vertical or horizontal) but can't find anywhere how to do it...
Maybe I should not navigate in my app like that ?
Can you help me if you have any answer on how to do it ?
thanks ! (for some reasons I can't say hello on my post ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HorizontalPager or VerticalPager from Accompanist.

https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/

```
                HorizontalPager(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    count = 10,
                    state = state
                ) { page ->
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "Screen $page")
                        }
                    }
```

An example https://github.com/google/horologist/blob/e2741cef87774b18d58bb1b0f78bd5b60901f20d/sample/src/main/java/com/google/android/horologist/scratch/ScratchActivity.kt#L79

If you want something more custom, then it's probably a serious investment in a component.  Especially if it needs to work with the system Swipe to Dismiss.